# How to compose a docker-compose to run npm natively and mongo in a docker

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to run node natively but run mongoDB in a container, just can't figure out the best way to do it.

Should run a command in the api dir and start npm?

I am trying to be able to deploy the whole application with a `docker-compose up`

Here are my files:

```
docker-compose.yml
/api
    Dockerfile
    package.json
/db
```

This is the `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    container_name: fl_api
    command: cd api && npm start
    ports:
      - "3002:3002"
    environment:
      DB_PORT: "27017"
      DB_HOST: mongo
      PORT: "3002"
    networks:
      - api_net

  mongo:
    container_name : fl_mongodb
    image: mongo:4.0
    volumes:
      - ./db/mong-vol:/data/db
    networks:
      - api_net
    expose:
      - "27017"
    healthcheck:
      test: echo 'db.stats().ok' | mongo localhost:27017/zenbrain --quiet
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 12

networks:
  api_net:
    driver: bridge
```

This is the `api/Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:6
WORKDIR /food-license-backend
COPY package.json /food-license-backend
RUN npm install
COPY . /food-license-backend
EXPOSE 3002
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Comment: I'm confused.  Every service in a docker-compose.yml file must have either an image or a build context associated with it.  I'm not sure what you mean by "natively".  If you mean to just use docker-compose to launch commands that aren't run in containers, then it won't do that.  But you can run a stock image, like _alpine_ for example, and set a command to run in that container.  Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Or maybe you just need to set a build context for _api_?  `build:` > `context: api/.`  Is that all you need?   https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build